# How to use exit code as conditional in simple 2 line bash script

Tags: bash

```
url="http://localhost:8080/matlib"
until $(curl "$url" --max-time 10) == 0; do stuck_pid=$(chown_pid); kill -9 $stuck_pid && "killing chmod process";done
```

what I'm trying to do is curl this address, if it times out after 10 seconds, then term a PID.

The part that is failing is the '== 0', the intention here was to compare the return code from curl with 0, but I'm receiving the following error:

```
-bash: ==: command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

This indeed is the problem:

```
$(curl "$url" --max-time 10) == 0
```

`==` operator must be inside `[[ ... ]]` or `[ ... ]` square brackets.

However you are not comparing exit status of `curl` but output of `curl` since you are executing `$(...)` or command substitution.

You should be using just:

```
until curl "$url" --max-time 10; do ...; done
```

Comment: `0` means success in shell and when you execute `until curl "$url" --max-time 10; do ...; done` it only checks for exit code `0`.